# Prevent query string tampering

Tags: php, query-string

I have written a script where I need to pass user information in url as query string to next page but if I alter the passed parameters the actual data related to that page also changes so how to prevent the alteration/tampering of query string. I don't usually use query strings so I don't really know the best way to secure them from tampering.

**Usage #1:**

```
<button class="btn btn-blue btn-xs">
    <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
    <a href="comment.php?u_id='.$row['id'].'&v_no='.$row['vault_no'].'"> Comment</a>
</button>
```

**Usage #2:**

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="GET" class="m-t" role="form" action="profile_1.php" autocomplete="off">
    <!--Field parameters-->
    <input style="vertical-align: middle" type="submit" name = "receive" id="submit" value="Post"  class="button">
```

**This is how I will process the query:**

```
if (isset($_GET['Receive'])) {      
    //receiving get parameters
    $xyz = $_GET['xyz'];
    $abc = $_GET['abc'];
```

Comment: Are you saying that your application writes `?id=2` and you don't want someone to manually put `?id=3` in the address bar *(just an example)*

Comment: @Rasclatt yeh exactly..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not stop users form tampering, whether by `$_GET` query tampering or by `cURL`-based queries, that's just the way it is, but you can make it harder for a user to tamper by using encryption or tokens. Just assume that if you have any kind of user input, it can be tampered with. *Quick note, I am not a an expert in cryptography by any stretch of the imagination, so don't take this as canon. You should do some more research depending on your needs.* If you need to persist data of a logged in user, you should probably think about using sessions instead of passing via a `$_GET` query.

**TWO-WAY DATA ENCRYPTION:**

Depending on your needs, something like [openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) might be an option. I use this type of thing if I want to transport data but don't necessarily want the end user to see in plaintext. I would never transport sensitive data client-side, but if you want to deter your users from messing around, this function library may be of some use.

Proper implementation of `openssl_encrypt()` will give you a string similar to:

```
nGaotAznsYN69aU%2BNun90vguvhQzk8KW%2BI2RZoom28YqKr05HTeSwPYbMgnPlepj
```

So in a query string it would look like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/?val=nGaotAznsYN69aU%2BNun90vguvhQzk8KW%2BI2RZoom28YqKr05HTeSwPYbMgnPlepj">CLICK</a>
```

With this method, if the decryption fails `openssl_decrypt()` (because tampering has wrecked the string) the decode should return `empty`, so you just account for `empty`:

```
// $dec would be the decrypted data from $_GET['val']
if(empty($dec))
    die('Invalid data.');
```

**NONCE / TOKEN(S):**

If it is the action that you want to protect (you want to make sure only a certain user or group can run an action in your app) you can try storing and checking against an [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). WordPress is one application that uses `nonce` quite heavily.

If it is the data itself you want to keep, you may want to have two-point authentication by using a couple *randomly-generated* tokens where you save a pair to a database with the real values stored in the same row so when the query is made, you can match the two tokens and return the actual data (or action word to allow your program to react accordingly):

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/?key=213Adfa316&token=9821745uwnwoi62626novVBei1qu4p">CLICK</a>

<!--
// the key and token would be in the database along with the corresponding data or action to take,
// you would have to figure that out...
// Then you would just use a select statement to get the data back:
// OF COURSE YOU WOULD BIND VALUES HERE!!!
-->

$smt = "SELECT `savedData` FROM `action_table` where `rKey`='213Adfa316' AND `rToken`='9821745uwnwoi62626novVBei1qu4p'"
```

**Note:** There are a lot of different ways to do the same sort of thing but if you are using a framework, there is probably a method that is native to that framework. I would do a bit more research on other methods but hopefully this will help to give you some ideas. As noted by *@zaph* it is important to implement encryption properly. Also noted by *@zaph* if security is the goal, using `https` will be the way to secure client/server communication. Also a good point to keep in mind is that query strings can be stored by the browser as part of the url history or server as part of the log so if you need one-time use URLs, you need to accommodate for that re-use policy.

Comment: @zaph I have not claimed security anywhere in my post, I have noted the user should not pass sensitive data client-side and should do more research in this area. I have suggested plausible ways to help validate query strings by implementing tokens or two-way encryption. I have given options to look into and I have posted from what I have used in the past that I now know is not accurate, thanks to your insight. I will delete those portions of this post so as not to pass on any *serious flaws* on to unsuspecting viewers.

Comment: @zaph As a side note, I do appreciate the comments, it is good information to work from. It tells me I have a lot more work to do in this area, because let's face it, we all want the highest security in the things we are working on. No one wants *their* script to be the source of a major security breach. Anyway I appreciate the insight.

Comment: Security is neither easy not quick to learn, my friend who does this full-time had their security vetted for the first 10 years.

Comment: @zaph I don't doubt it. Security is definitely a specialty, especially when your adversaries are so highly-skilled. I should reiterate that I really only come up with these two options because the OP is trying to deal with query string tampering. I doesn't sound like they are trying to send sensitive data (I hope not through `$_GET` for sure) but doing encryption on a query string will deter 99.9% of users from trying to tamper. If implemented properly, like you say, I think it is a very solid solution...but I personally would not send sensitive data through `$_GET` even still...

Comment: @zaph I will add the `https` comment because that is also a good point to make for security sake.

Comment: I think you're on the right track here, but any answer in this department comes with a number of caveats. If this is being deployed in an environment handling sensitive information **get your code audited by certified security professionals**.

Comment: @tadman Agreed, security is not something to play around with.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion's.!!

Comment: sir.! as am new to these concept i would like to ask you that how shall i implement openssl_encrypt() in my script, i.e in a query string in "href"?

Comment: @Hari Look at the first edit of this answer, you can see what I originally posted. There is an example there, but make note, the `ENC_SALT` should be 32 characters long, not 16 and you should take note of the answer by *tadman*. You should expire the password. I would look at the php manual, there may be some helpful contributor notes. Finally, do not send sensitive data through `$_GET`.

Comment: If you feel the answer I gave was useful or correct, feel free to check it off as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to this is if information is really sensitive, **don't send it** to anyone. Keep it local. You can send a reference to this information instead, use that as a token to retrieve it on a later request.

For example, generate a UUID, save a document containing your sensitive information in some local data store, and link the UUID in the URL. There's not really a whole lot of useful information that can be gleaned from a UUID, at least none pertaining to what's inside the secret store.

A short-term data store like [Redis](http://redis.io/) is handy for this sort of persistence. You can set a TTL on your data so it will be purged automatically at some point in the future. An expiration time of 24-48 hours should be enough, and if you need to extend this expiration each time it's used that's possible.

A truly random UUID will be impractical to guess. Anyone trying to brute-force this should be caught by a rate-limiting mechanism on your server if that's an issue.

Answer (score -1):

**Hi You can use first approach. Below is your solution**

**1. If using without php Tag**

```
<a href="comment.php?u_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&v_no=<?php echo $row['vault_no']; ?>">Click Here</a>
```

**2. If Useing with in Php tag**

```
<?php 
echo "<a href='comment.php?u_id=".$row['id']."&v_no=".$row['vault_no']."'>Check Here2</a>"
?>
```

Comment: I have updated my href_qstring.php code please give me some idea over that..!! sorry but your code is throwing error in phpcodechecker.com

Comment: What does this do to prevent tampering? It just generates a link.